# Add image for tabbaritem but it not show in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I create a *tabbarcontroller* including many `UINavigationcontroller`, but it cannot show image in each *tabbaritem*.

You can see this picture:

[image]

I used this code to create `uitabbarcontroller` :

```
// FirstViewController
UploadTab *uploadview=[[UploadTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *uploadTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: uploadview] autorelease];
uploadview.title=@"Uploading";
uploadview.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uploading.png"];

//SecondViewController
ConvertTab *convertView=[[ConvertTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *convertTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: convertView] autorelease];
convertView.title=@"Convert";
convertView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Convert.png"];

//ThirdViewController
CompletedTab *completedView=[[CompletedTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *completedTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: completedView] autorelease];
completedView.title=@"Completed";
completedView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Completed.png"];

NSArray *viewControllersArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:uploadTabItem,convertTabItem, completedTabItem, nil];
self.tab.viewControllers=viewControllersArray;


 [self presentModalViewController:self.tab animated:NO];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: as @sbarrow said you assign tabbar image to navigation controller instance

Comment: can you show us the images? do you know that only the alpha channel is relevant for the icons?

Comment: This is properties of image : Demension : 30x30, Resolution : 299 pixel/inch, Color space RGB, Alpha Channel : YEs

Comment: naming matches exactly ?

Comment: Sure naming matches exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom icon that you provide for a toolbar, navigation bar, or tab bar is also known as a template image, because iOS uses it as a mask to create the icon you see in your app. It is not necessary to create a full-color template image.

After you’ve decided on the appearance of your icon, follow these guidelines as you create it:

1. Use pure white with appropriate alpha transparency.
2. Do not include a drop shadow.
3. Use anti-aliasing.
4. If you decide to add a bevel, be sure that it is 90° (to help you do this, imagine a light source positioned at the top of the icon).

For tab bar icons on iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad, create an icon in the following sizes:

About 30 x 30 pixels (48 x 32 pixels maximum)
About 60 x 60 pixels (96 x 64 pixels maximum) for high resolution

Comment: The spec says "Use pure white with **appropriate** alpha transparency" but what is does "appropriate" mean? What does that refer to?  What should be white (background, icon)?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that your images meet the requirement specified in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
// FirstViewController
UploadTab *uploadview=[[UploadTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *uploadTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController: uploadview] autorelease];
uploadTabItem.title=@"Uploading";
uploadTabItem.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uploading.png"];
```

Comment: what is the size of uploading.png?

Comment: size of image is 30x30

Comment: Try delete the application, build and run again.

Comment: Reset  your simulator and clean the build and run thereafter

Answer (score 0):

Go to Uploadview or the view you are creating, and in init method set self.tabbaritem setimage and settitle.It may work

Comment: Thanks but it not work, in UploadView i tried [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uploading.png"]];